# Given parent node array, print out preorder traversal of the tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, preorder

Given an unsorted node array where node is defined as: 
 `Node {   int id;
     int parent_id;
     string label; 
 }`

Each node has its own unique id. `parent_id` identify its parent in the tree. The question is how to do an preorder traversal of the tree? (not necessarily a binary tree)

This is an interview question that has troubled me for several days. What I can think of is to use a hash map `map<int,list<node> >` where key is the parentid. Then I cannot go further. Should I build the tree from map and do a preorder traversal or if there is a good way to do it directly from the map? Then how? Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything that specifies the order of the children? You can mark the root node while constructing the map and then just traverse that map in preorder starting from the root.

Answer (score 1):

So you need:

```
map<int, list<Node> > childMap;
map<int, Node> nodeMap;
```

You'll find a node that doesn't have a parent (parent_id = -1 or something), this is obviously the root. You call the below function for that node after setting up the maps above.

```
preOrder(int id)
{
  process(nodeMap[id]);
  foreach (Node node: childMap[id])
    preOrder(node);
}
```

Comment: Great answer. A DFS would suffice.